# Dependencies between Features

Tags: bdd, specifications, gherkin

We're having our first attempt at writing some Gherkin specs for a greenfield application and I'm not sure how to tackle what appear to be inter-dependant features.

Essentially, we have a feature `CreateADoor` that is actually used as part of two other features `BuildAHouse` and `BuildAShed`.

The `CreateADoor` feature is relatively complex in terms of validation etc. which is why we have lifted it out as a seperate feature (to avoid duplication).  The issue is that the *result* of scenarios for this feature are dependant on the context they were called from (should my newly built door be on a House or a Shed).

The only way I can really see to solve this is to get rid of `CreateADoor` and have its scenarios duplicated inside both `BuildAHouse` and `BuildAShed`.  In this specific situation this would be (just about) bearable, but what about the situation where `CreateADoor` requires 10 scenarios to spec it out, and is used by 10 different features.  Having 10 scenarios explode out into 100 doesn't seem good, but I can't see another option at the minute.

Can anyone suggest a different approach that allows us to avoid this explosion of scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should not create these dependencies, but instead if creating a door is part of building a house then the building a house feature should create a door as part of its setup instead of reusing the feature to test creating a door.

This might look like this:

```
Given I have created a house door
When I create a house
Then I should be able to live in it
```

and the logic for creating the door should be in the code behind the Given step. This logic might be very different from what actually happens when you create a door in the tests.

If you can't separate things like this then one thing I have done in the past is to make the code behind the `Given` step call the other steps from the `CreateADoor` feature so that the code is not duplicated, but the existing steps are reused.  This is not ideal, but pragmatically this is sometimes necessary.

Comment: I'm more concerned with things from a documentation/spec point of view.  The spec around creating a door (valid/invalid examples etc) is relatively complex and I need to have this defined somewhere

Comment: I'm suggesting keeping the specs for creating a door, and then either 1/ create a door as the setup for creating a house with totally separate code (doesn't need the validation etc), or 2/ reusing the steps from the create a door scenarios in the create a house scenario in order to create a door for the house